# doing multicore programming when CPU intensive applications are running in background?

Tags: linux, multithreading, ubuntu, cpu-usage, multicore

My question is: how will the results of multi-core programs get affected if I have some CPU intensive applications running in the background? Will the quality of my results be affected by these applications?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "the quality of my results"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the multi-core programs in question do not have bugs in them, such as race conditions, the results should be the same, although they will probably take longer to complete since some of the CPU cycles they would have used will be allocated instead to the other programs.

If the programs in question are time-sensitive (e.g. audio/video players, video games, robot-controllers, etc), the slower performance might in itself be a problem, since a time-sensitive program that doesn't get CPU time when it wants it can result in glitches in the playback, or a video game updating too slowly to be enjoyable, or the robot not responding quickly to keep itself from falling over, or etc.

But for programs that do strictly non-real-time batch/computational work, the computational results will be the same.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question.. the programs in question are time-sensitive so I guess installing compiz (A CPU-intensive application) would not be a good idea!
But, please confirm my understand esp. with respect to Compiz software (ccsm to be specific, used for the fancy effects on ubuntu linux)!

Comment: I'm not familiar with compiz, so I can't confirm or deny anything about that.  I would say that if you do run it, try to make sure that it runs at lower priority than your time-sensitive tasks -- or better yet just don't run it at all; if all it does for you is make your GUI prettier, that's a pretty trivial benefit that's easy to go without.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! That's true.. making my GUI pretty is not as important as running those multi-core programs faster!

Comment: Update: I found that compiz actually does not consume much CPU cycles! it's hardly upto 5% based on what the system monitor showed me on Ubuntu..

Comment: Besides, I now run my multi-core programs on powerful servers not my own local machine.. so, I'm good now!